# PowerShell filter registry ItemProperty

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to retrieve properties from a Windows registry key, but I want to exclude two specific properties. I have attempted multiple approaches, but all of my attempts have returned all of the properties from the registry key. Here is my PowerShell code that I have tried:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload\" |
    Where-Object {"PSParentPath", "PSPath" -notcontains $_.Name}
```

I am using Windows 10.19044.2965 with Windows PowerShell 5.119041.2674. How can I retrieve all properties except for "PSParentPath" and "PSPath" from the registry key mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

`Get-ItemProperty` outputs a single object with all the requested properties. Use `Select-Object` to reshape it:

```
$path = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload\"
Get-ItemProperty -Path $path |Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*
```

Comment: You can also exclude a list of properties: `-ExcludeProperty PSParentPath, PSPath`